# Array calculation in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to know whether I can use python to write a program on this question. 
I have three arrays:

```
A = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6']
B = ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6']
C = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']
```

I need to get one element from each array at one time, put them together and print it, for example, 'a1b1c1'.

Every grouped element can only appear once regardless of sequence.

Each element must group with new elements from the other two arrays in each round. 
For example, in the 1st loop, 'a1', 'b1','c1' has been chosen, in the following rounds, if 'a1' has been chosen again, neither 'b1' nor 'c1' can be chosen. 
How can I write a loop in Python and print all the possible results? Thank you.

```
A = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6']
B = ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6']
C = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']

for i in range(len(A)):
    a=A[i]
    for j in range(len(B)):
        b=B[j]
        for h in range(len(C)):
            c=C[h]
            print a+b+c
```

Let me use 3 arrays with 3 elements as an example because a list of 6 elements is too long.

Expected results: 
a1,b1,c1

a1,b2,c2

a1,b3,c3

a2,b1,c2

a2,b2,c3

a2,b3,c1

a3,b1,c3

a3,b2,c1

a3,b3,c2

Comment: Downvoted, as you have not mentioned any effort that you have made on your end. Please post your code.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question, but you might want to have a look at `itertools` and maybe `itertools.permutations`

Comment: You need to clarify what your expected output is. I _think_ you can do what you want using `itertools.product`, or maybe  `itertools.combinations`, but it's hard to tell. BTW, you probably got those downvotes because your question isn't clear and because you didn't post your own code attempt.

Comment: I think I've figured out what you want to do, but I'm still not certain. If 'a1b1c1'  has already been printed is 'a2b1c1' allowed? IOW, I think you're saying that if we've printed 'a1b1c1'  then none of  'axb1c1',  'a1byc1', or 'a1b1cz' are legal for any other x, y, or z. Is that correct? If so, a valid set of combinations from your lists contains 28 triplets.

Comment: Hi, PM 2Ring. Yes, if 'a1b1c1' has been printed, combination of any two of 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'  should not appear.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am checking how to use itertools now

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample output, and your own code attempt.

Comment: FWIW, my previous algorithm was incorrect, so it didn't find as many combinations as it could have found. I see now that if the length of the lists is `n`, the number of combinations is `n²`. And there's a fairly efficient way to generate those combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:
ok, after a more clear explanation of the problem, I think this is more like what you need:

```
import random
for strA in A:
    l = len(B)
    nB = random.randrange(l)
    nC = random.randrange(l)
    for i in range(l):
        posB = (i + nB)%l
        posC = (i + nC)%l
        print(strA + B[posB] + C[posC])
```

It takes every element of A, and it appends one element of B and C in order but starting from a random position and without repetitions. Is this it?

Comment: You can do this with a single `for` loop and `itertools.product`, rather than a triple `for` loop. However, this is probably _not_ what the OP wants, since the question states that if 'a1b1c1' is produced no later outputs containing 'a1' can contain either 'b1' or 'c1'.

Comment: He basically wants all the a, b and c combinations so that's what he gets

Comment: No, he _doesn't_ want all the a, b and c combinations. "in the 1st loop, 'a1', 'b1','c1' has been chosen, in the following rounds, if 'a1' has been chosen again, neither 'b1' nor 'c1' can be chosen". But it's still not totally clear what he actually _does_ want.

Comment: Hi Shinra, this is the first thing I tried. I think PM 2Ring explains very clearly.

Comment: Honestly, I think you should have explained clearly what you wanted the output to be, because explaining it in human language can be confusing.

Comment: ok, I understand now, for every a, you want a b and a c to appear only once with it. The b and the c have to be certain values, or random among the ones you have?

Comment: Random from the arrays.

Comment: Ok, try it now.